# Simple inheritance implementation for JS: is this a good example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, inheritance

Coming from Dojo, I *really* miss a *lot* Dojo's `declare()` function.
I am developing a complex-ish application, and I hacked the living hell out of Node's `lang.inherits()` to make it more... well, more powerful.

Here is an example to show you what it actually does:

```
var First = declare( null, {
  one: function(p){ 
    console.log("one in First");
    console.log(p); 
    return 1000; 
  },
  two: function(p){ 
    console.log("two in First");
    console.log(p);
    return 1001; 
  },
  constructor: function(a){ 
    this.a = a; 
    console.log("Constructor of First called");
  },
})

var Second = declare( First, {
  two: function( p ){
    console.log("two in Second"); 
    console.log( p );
    a = this.inherited(arguments);
    console.log("Inherited function returned: " + a );
  },
  constructor: function(a){ 
    console.log("Constructor of Second called, and this.a is...");
    console.log( this.a );
  },
})

console.log("Creating first...");
first = new First(10);
console.log("Creating second...");
second = new Second( 20 );

console.log( "first.a:")
console.log( first.a );
console.log( "second.a:")
console.log( second.a );

console.log( "first.one(1):")
first.one(1);
console.log( "first.two(2):")
first.two(2);

console.log( "second.one(3):")
second.one(3);
console.log( "second.two(4):")
second.two(4);
```

Will display:

```
Creating first...
Constructor of First called
Creating second...
Constructor of First called
Constructor of Second called, and this.a is...
20
first.a:
10
second.a:
20
first.one(1):
one in First
1
first.two(2):
two in First
2
second.one(3):
one in First
3
second.two(4):
two in Second
4
two in First
4
Inherited function returned: 1001
```

I know that the function `lang.inherits()` is minimalistic for a reason: nodejs doesn't want to impose specific ways of dealing with "classes", prototypes, and objects in Javascript.

However, a lot of code out there is full of:

```
function SomeClass( options ){
  this.options = options;
}

SomeClass.prototype.functionOne = function(something){
  //...
}
SomeClass.prototype.functionTwo = function(something){
  //...
}
```

Which could (and... well, should?) be written as:

```
SomeClass = declare( null, {
  constructor: function(options){
    this.options = options;
  },
  functionOne: function(something){
    // ...
  },
  functionTwo: function(something){
    // ...
  },
})
```

With the benefit of being able to do:

```
SomeOtherClass = declare( SomeClass, {
  constructor: function(){
    this.options['manipulate'] ++;
  },
  functionOne: function(something){
    this.inherited(arguments); // Call the superclass method
    // ...
  },
})
```

Which will automatically call the constructor of the parent etc.
(To implement `this.inherited()` I actually ended up creating a hash map of the functions, as they are effectively name-less);

The major difference between this and Dojo's is that this version doesn't implement multiple inheritance and mixins. However, while multiple inheritance/mixins make sense in a client-side environment, I feel that they would be a major overkill in a server-side program.
OK... here is the code.
Can you spot anything really wrong with this code?

Did I invent something that already existed?

Here we go...

```
var 
  dummy
;

var declare = exports.declare = function(superCtor, protoMixin) {

  // Kidnap the `constructor` element from protoMixin, as this
  // it mustn't get copied over into the prototype
  var constructor = protoMixin.constructor;
  delete protoMixin.constructor;

  // The function that will work as the effective constructor. This
  // will be returned
  var ctor = function(){

    // Call the superclass constructor automatically
    if( typeof( superCtor.prototype.constructor === 'function' ) ){
       superCtor.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    // Call its own constuctor (kidnapped a second ago)
    if( typeof( constructor ) === 'function' ){
      constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    }
  };

  // The superclass can be either an empty one, or the one passed
  // as a parameter
  superCtor = superCtor === null ? function(){} : superCtor;

  // Create the new class' prototype. It's a new object, which happen to
  // have its own prototype (__proto__) set as the superclass' and the
  // `constructor` attribute set as ctor (the one we are about to return)
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });

  // Implement inherited() so that classes can run this.inherited(arguments)
  // This will only work for sub-classes created using declare() as they are
  // the ones with the _inheritMap in their prototype
  protoMixin.inherited = function(args){
    var name, fn;

    // Look for the name in the _inheritMap
    name = this._inheritMap[ args.callee ];
    if( name ){
      fn = superCtor.prototype[name];
      if( fn ){
        return fn.apply( this, args );
      } else {
        throw( new Error("Method " + name + "() not inherited!") );
      }
    }
  }

  // Copy every element in protoMixin into the prototype.
  ctor.prototype._inheritMap = {}
  for( var k in protoMixin ){
    ctor.prototype[ k ] = protoMixin[ k ];
    ctor.prototype._inheritMap[ protoMixin[ k ] ] = k;
  }

  return ctor;
};
exports = module.exports = declare;
```

Comment: Im a huge coffeescript fan and I think that your should give it a try. It does pretty much all you need in terms of inheritance.

Comment: Yep but I am not a coffeescrpt kind of guy :D

Comment: does the inherited method works with several levels of inheritance ?

Comment: It sure does, it just uses JS's prototypes. The only "magic" is with the calling of the constructor, and the this.inherited(arguments)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer I suppose is "if it works, then great!".
It works... so: great!

For future reference, "declare" is on GitHub:

https://github.com/mercmobily/JsonRestStores/blob/master/declare.js

I updated the code so that this.inherited(arguments) works without the hashmap.

For now, it's part of:

https://github.com/mercmobily/JsonRestStores

Even though I might as well create a separate repository, since it *is* a handy function to have in its own right!

Merc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at `npm install declarejs`, which is basically a ripped out version of Dojo's declare.

You can find a bit more info [here](https://npmjs.org/package/declarejs)

Personally I prefer something like Backbone's `.extend()`, which can easily be ripped out.